# Apache storm error when submitting topology locally

Tags: java, apache-storm, topology

I'm trying to submit my Storm topology locally.  However, I keep receiving this error on the console when calling `cluster.submitTopology()`:

> [Thread-5] ERROR backtype.storm.event - Error when processing event
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn:
>   'backtype.storm.util/some?
>
> [Thread-5] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Error when
>   processing an event")

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("twitterspout", new TwitterSpout());
    builder.setBolt("sentiment", new SentimentBolt()).shuffleGrouping("twitterspout");
    builder.setBolt("dimension", new DimensionBolt()).shuffleGrouping("twitterspout");
    builder.setBolt("clustering", new ClusteringBolt())
    .fieldsGrouping("dimension", new Fields("dimension"))
    .fieldsGrouping("sentiment", new Fields("sentiment"));

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);


    System.out.print("Creating local Cluster...");
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    System.out.println("Done!");

    cluster.submitTopology("enrichment", conf, builder.createTopology());

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the `DimensionBolt` actually emitting a `dimension` field? same for `SentimentBolt`?

Comment: I improved readability of your code, using standard JAVA convention

Comment: Possibility is that, any of your bolt is throwing error. Please post the full stacktrace, for better understanding.